# Function $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth iff $f\circ\phi^{-1}$ is smooth for every chart $\phi$

Tags: solution-verification, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am trying to solve exercise 6.5 of Loring Tu's book ["An Introduction to Manifolds"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4419-7400-6) which states that a function $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$ on a smooth manifold $M$ is smooth if, and only if for every chart $(U,\phi)$ on $M$,  $f\circ \phi^{-1}$ is smooth on $\phi(U)$. As far as I understand, I have to consider $\phi(U)$, which is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for some $n \ge 1$, as a manifold itself (a submanifold).

My attempt is as follows.

Suppose $f$ is smooth and $\phi$ a chart on $M$. Take $1_{\phi(U)}: \phi(U) \to \phi(U)$ to be the identity map $1_{\phi(U)}(x) = x$. It is a chart on $\phi(U)$ because it is compatible with the identity map $\operatorname{Id}: \mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}^{n}$, so it is contained in the differentiable structure of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Moreover $f\circ \phi^{-1}\circ 1_{\phi(U)}$ is smooth because $f\circ \phi^{-1}$ is smooth map by hypothesis. Hence, $f\circ \phi^{-1}$ is smooth on $\phi(U)$.

Conversely, suppose if $f\circ \phi^{-1}$ is smooth for every chart $(U,\phi)$ on $M$, then $f = (f\circ \phi^{-1}\circ \phi)$ is smooth on $U$ because it is the composite of smooth functions.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Which book ? he has at least 2 books ?

Comment: If I remember correctly this is exactly the *definition* of a smooth function $f: M \to \Bbb R$ used by Tu in his book *An Introduction to Manifolds*, so I assume this is not the book you are using. How does he define smooth functions in the book you have?

Comment: @DouglasFinamore there are two related concepts here. Yes, a function $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable if there exists some chart $(U,\phi)$ on $M$ such that $f \circ \phi^{-1}$ is differentiable. But here differentiable means the usual notion of differentiability of a function from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. However, since $\phi$ is a homeomorphism, $\phi(U)$ is open and it can be treated as a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and we can ask whether $f\circ \phi^{-1}$ is differentiable as a function from a submanifold to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: As far as I understand, the exercise is about proving that $f\circ \phi^{-1}$ in the second case because, otherwise, the statement of the exercise is the very definition of differentiability as you pointed out and there is nothing to do at all.

Comment: Oh, I see what what's is going on here. In the definition he says that a function $f$ is smooth around a point $p$ if there is a chart  $(U, \phi)$ containing that point such that $f \circ \phi^{-1}$ is smooth at $\phi(p)$. The exercise is to show that if $f$ is smooth then **every** chart $(V, \psi)$ around that point satisfy the condition that $f\circ\psi$ is smooth at $\psi(p)$. So you're only using the notion of differentiability on $\Bbb R^n$ in the end. The point of the exercise is to show that the choice of chart doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

I see from your arguments that you're trying to make use of the definition of a smooth map between manifolds, but that's not really necessary. As I pointed out in my commment, the point of the exercise is simply to show that the choice of chart in the definition of smooth function doesn't matter.

Indeed, suppose $f: M \to \Bbb R$ is smooth at $x$. By definition, this means the existence of a chart $(U, \phi)$ around $x$ such that $f \circ \phi^{^1}: \phi(U) \to R$ is smooth (i.e., $C^\infty$) at $\phi(x)$.

Now, given any other chart $(V, \psi)$ around $x$, the point $\psi(x)$ lies in the open set $\psi(U\cap V) \subset \Bbb R$, and in this open we can write the function $f \circ \psi$ as a composition
$$ f \circ \psi^{-1} = (f \circ \phi^{-1}) \circ (\phi \circ \psi^{-1}): \psi (U \cap V) \to \Bbb R.$$
Now $f \circ \phi^{^1}$ is smooth at $\phi(x)$ by the definition of smoothness for the function $f$, while $\phi \circ \psi^{-1}$ is smooth at $\psi(x)$ because transition maps are smooth by definition.

Hence $f \circ \psi^{-1}$ is smooth at $\psi(x)$, and we see that $f$ satisfy the smoothness condition in any chart around $x$.